# Strange enum behavior with ternary operators

Tags: c, enums

I was writing a very simple ternary operator with one of my enum and I stumbled upon what is a very strange error (to me..). Given this piece of code:

```
typedef enum
{
    first = 0,
    second,
    last
}myEnum;

myEnum myVar = first;

(myVar < second) ? myVar++ : myVar = last;
```

The compiler sent me the following error:

> error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment

Where as if I simply change the ternary to a if/else block like this :

```
if(myVar < second)
{
    myVar++;
}
else
{
    myVar = last;
}
```

Everything compiles and works fine. Can somebody explain why the exact same code written as a ternary won't compile? What am I missing?

Comment: @dyp "the third part of a ternary operator cannot be an assignment-expression" Why not? If you put parentheses appropriately, it should work (but may confuse the reader).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your expression is parsed as:

```
( (myVar < second) ? myVar++ : myVar ) = last;
```

but you seem to have intended to do:

```
(myVar < second) ? myVar++ : (myVar = last);
```

This is actually not exactly what the standard mandates (but many compilers parse it that way), the first expression should actually fail for another reason (a syntax error rather than a constraint violation).

C99 6.5.15 says:

```
conditional-expression:
    logical-OR-expression
    logical-OR-expression ? expression : conditional-expression
```

and `myVar = last` is not a *conditional-expression* but an *assignment-expression* (C99 6.5.16):

```
assignment-expression:
    conditional-expression
    unary-expression assignment-operator assignment-expression
```

but `(myVar < second) ? myVar++ : myVar` is not an *unary-expression* (see C99 6.5.3) (but the parenthesized version thereof would be, that is as I wrote in my first code snippet, see C99 6.5.1).

HTH

Comment: You're right my expression wasn't parsed as I intended. Kinda tricky imo that must be 1 of the reason people say to avoid ternary.. What is HTH btw?

Comment: @Asics: “Hope this helps”. And another thing: Note, that the second operand of the ternary operator is an _expression_, not a _conditional-expression_, so `myVar>=second ? myVar=last : myVar++` works…

Answer (score 3):

What you do and what you try to do is not comparable.

This one

```
if(myVar < second)
{
    myVar++;
}
else
{
    myVar = last;
}
```

translates to

```
myVar = (myvar < second) ? myvar + 1 : last;
```

If you want to completely build on side effects, you can as well do

```
(myVar < second) ? myVar++ : (myVar = last);
```

but I am not sure this is good style as it might confuse the reader about the intention of the expression.