# Ternary operator and lvalues in C

Tags: c

Suppose I have a linked list L which may be NULL or not. When I try

```
   !L ? s+=2 : t+=2;
```

The compiler complains that lvalue is required as left operand of assignment. What am I missing? Operator precedence, maybe?

Comment: Yes, precedence. See e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24491865/1741125). Or just do `!L ? s+=2 : (t+=2)`.

Comment: not sure if this works in C, but if it was java, you might fix it by simply adding a couple parentheses to make the intent more clear.

Comment: Since you did not specify what `s` and `t` are, does it work with a "normal" `if/else` block?

Comment: @barakmanos: They're `int`s. @mafso is right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The relevant grammar production is:

> *conditional-expression*:
>
> > *logical-OR-expression*
> >
> > *logical-OR-expression* **?** *expression* **:** *conditional-expression*

`t+=2` is not a *conditional-expression*, so the compiler must interpret `!L ? s+=2 : t+=2` as equivalent to `(!L ? s+=2 : t)+=2`. In C, a conditional expression never yields an lvalue, so cannot appear to the left of `+=`.

`(t+=2)` is a *conditional-expression*, so `!L ? s+=2 : (t+=2)` is correct.

---

For reference, in C++ the relevant grammar production is:

> *conditional-expression*:
>
> > *logical-or-expression*
> >
> > *logical-or-expression* **?** *expression* **:** *assignment-expression*

`t+=2` is an *assignment-expression*, so `!L ? s+=2 : t+=2` is valid C++, and does what you think.

Interestingly, in C++, the conditional operator can yield an lvalue, if the undecayed common type of its second and third operands is an lvalue. But if my reading of the standard is correct, then this fact has no bearing on this case.

Answer (score 2):

In C you should use parentheses in the second term, because of operator precedence as you thought.
`!L ? s+=2 : (t+=2);`

In C++, you don't need the parentheses.

Comment: For my curiosity, could you clarify how the compiler is trying to interpret the original snippet, and why the parentheses fixes that?

Comment: @Riley I think the other answer covers your question. :)